# Using a For loop to find the sum of positive even numbers and negative odd numbers in python

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop

Have a problem which asks to find the sum of the positive even numbers and negative odd numbers, 1 to 100 (So 1+2-3+4....+98-99+100). Here is what I have done so far and the correct sum should be 52 if I am doing my math correctly but I come out with a sum of 50. Any suggestions?

```
lst = range(1,101)
>>> total = 0
>>> for x in lst:
...     if x % 2:
...             total -= x
...     else:
...             total += x
...
>>> total
50
```

Comment: Why do you believe this is equal to 52? `sum(range(2, 101, 2)) - sum(range(1, 100, 2)) == 50`. Or just maths, `2+100 == 4+98 == ... = 102*25` and `1+99 == 3+97 == ... = 100*25`, so `102*25 - 100*25 = 50`.

Comment: your code didn't match your expire output. `1+2-3+4...+98-99+100`, `1` should be `-1` according to your describe.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your code is right and your math is wrong. Here are three ways to solve the problem.

your solution:

```
lst = range(1,101)
total = 0
for x in lst:
    if x % 2:
        total -= x
    else:
        total += x
print(total)
```

50

Sum of even numbers plus the sum of odd numbers:

```
def sumForLoop(max):
    positiveEven = sum(range(2,max+1,2))
    negativeOdd = -sum(range(1,max+1, 2))
    print(positiveEven + negativeOdd)
sumForLoop(100)
```

50

A formula for the total:

```
def sumFormula(max):
     print(-1**100 *math.floor(max/2))
sumFormula(100)
```

50